# ¿Cómo puedo indicar la cantidad de números que son múltiplos de 2 y mayores a 15 utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, condiciones, botón, contador

¡Hola! Quería permitirle al usuario ingresar un total de cinco números en un campo de texto y quería indicarle la cantidad de aquellos ingresos que sean múltiplos de 2, mayores a 15 o que cumplan ambos. El problema es que no sé ¿si debería aplicar otros contadores para las tres condiciones o si existe alguna manera de acortar dichas condiciones?

Les puedo dejar lo básico del código de jQuery abajo para también saber si voy bien encaminado:

```
$("#btnIngreso").click(determinarResultado);

let number;
let cantidadNumbers = 0;
let cantidadMultiplos = 0;

function determinarResultado(){
    cantidadNumbers += 1;
    if(cantidadNumbers<=5){
        number = Number($("#txtNumber").val());
        cantidadMultiplos = 0;
        if(number % 2 === 0){
            cantidadMultiplos += number;
            alert(cantidadMultiplos);
        }
        if(number>15){

        }
        if(number % 2 === 0 && number>15){

        }
    }
}
```

Esto sería la estructura básica del documento:

```
<body>
    <label for="txtNumber">Ingresar cinco números:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNumber">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngreso">
    <p id="pMultiplos"></p>
    <p id="pMayores"></p>
    <p id="pAmbos"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: pero como el usuario pone varios en una caja de text? Separados por comas? O hay varias cajas? O una caja de texto con boton de añadir?

Comment: Pensé que si acumulaba o contaba las cantidades en un campo de texto se me simplificaría el proceso, así no tendría que agregar otros campos. En este caso, solamente le dejé un campo de texto para que ingrese esos 5 números a elección para determinar dichas condiciones que podría llegar a cumplir.

Comment: pero es lo que pregunto si el usuario tiene que ingresar 5 numeros de golpe. O de uno en uno

Comment: Ah, sí, sería de uno en uno en el mismo campo.

Comment: tal como lo tienes planteado es correcto. Como son condiciones distintas y necesitas mostrar cuantos hay de cada condición pues necesitas 3 contadores. Cuando aumentas el contador tienes que sumar `cantidadMultiplos++ ` no el numero que has leido

Comment: Bien, ¡muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te puede servir. Necesitas algo para separar los números, de otra manera solo tomaría el número completo como un solo número. Si deseas que se vaya guardando en una variable el número que vas ingresando por separado, debes hacer uso de algún evento de onkeypress.

```js
function DeterminarResultado(){
  const numeros = $("#txtNumber").val().split(",")
  
  if(numeros.length > 5) return
  
  let multiplos = mayores = ambos = 0
  
  numeros.forEach(numero => {
    const Numero = parseFloat(numero)
    
    if(Numero % 2 == 0)
      multiplos++
    
    if(Numero > 15)
      mayores++
      
    if(Numero % 2 == 0 & Numero > 15)
      ambos++
  })
  
  $("#pMultiplos").html(`Multiplos: ${multiplos}`)
  $("#pMayores").html(`Mayores: ${mayores}`)
  $("#pAmbos").html(`Ambos: ${ambos}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label for="txtNumber">Ingresar números, separados por coma:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNumber">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngreso" onclick="DeterminarResultado()">
    <p id="pMultiplos"></p>
    <p id="pMayores"></p>
    <p id="pAmbos"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: PD: Trata de no utilizar variables globales. Utiliza variables dentro de tus funciones, eso te evitará muchos problemas.